# Fully maximizing Chrome on a large monitor

Tags: macos, firefox, google-chrome, osx-lion, external-display

I want to change from Firefox to Chrome. I do love Firefox, but my graphics card seems to handle YouTube a lot better when in Chrome.

I use a MacBook and connect it to an external monitor at work, so I have one 13" display (laptop) and one 24" (external). When I move the Chrome window to the external display and click the maximize button, it just makes the height of the window large but the width stays at the 13" width of the laptop so I end up with a long, tall window. When I do this in Firefox it will fill the external display completely.

Any idea how I can get Chrome to work like this?

Extra information: Mac OS X Lion, external monitor connected via HDMI

Comment: In response to your statement about Firefox and YouTube issues: Google Chrome ships with it's own version of Adobe Flash Player. You should try updating your Flash Player by going to [http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/](http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/) using Firefox., as well as your graphics card drivers.

Comment: thanks for the response, my flash is up to the latest version, i think the problem is just the graphics card its only a intel gma x3100 144mb and i think its begining  to show its age, chrome just seems to use it more efficently, the other thing ive found with firefox is it seems to have a memory leak problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shift-click the maximize button.